# Calculating Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

I want to verify the following equation:

$$E[(xe^{aY-\frac{1}{2}a^2}-b)^+]=x\Phi(l_1)-b\Phi(l_2)$$

where $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, $\Phi$ the distribution function of a standard normal distribution, constants $a,b,x$ and with $l_1=\frac{\log{\frac{x}{b}}+\frac{1}{2}a^2}{a}$, $l_2=\frac{\log{\frac{x}{b}}-\frac{1}{2}a^2}{a}$

This is what I've done: Let $A:=xe^{aY-\frac{1}{2}a^2}> b$, then

$$E[(xe^{aY-\frac{1}{2}a^2}-b)^+]=E[xe^{aY-\frac{1}{2}a^2}\mathbf1_A]-bP[A]$$

For the second term I got:

$$bP[A]=bP\left[Y>\frac{\log{\frac{b}{x}}+\frac{1}{2}a^2}{a}\right]=b\Phi\left(-\frac{\log{\frac{b}{x}}+\frac{1}{2}a^2}{a}\right)=b\Phi(l_2)$$

For the first term:

$$xE[e^{aY-\frac{1}{2}a^2}\mathbf1_A]=x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}a}\int_{\frac{b}{x}}^\infty e^{-\frac{(\log{y}+\frac{1}{2}a^2)^2}{2a^2}}\frac{1}{y}dy$$

I put $u:=\frac{\log{y}+\frac{1}{2}a^2}{a}$, hence $\frac{du}{dy}=\frac{1}{ay}$, or $dy=ay du$, therefore

$$x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}a}\int_{p}^\infty e^{-\frac{(\log{y}+\frac{1}{2}a^2)^2}{2a^2}}\frac{1}{y}dy=x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}a}\int_{p}^\infty e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}\frac{1}{y}aydu=x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{p}^\infty e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du$$

where $p=\frac{\log{\frac{b}{x}}+\frac{1}{2}a^2}{a}$, but then

$$x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{p}^\infty e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du=x\Phi(-p),$$ 
which is not equal to $x\Phi(l_1)$. So where is my mistake?

Comment: You forgot the factor $e^{aY-\frac12a^2}$ in the first integral written after "For the first term" (by the way, the way you compute this expectation is one of the most error-prone one can imagine...).

Comment: @Did Thanks! I will redo the calculations. So what would be a less error-prone way to calculate it?

Comment: To use directly the fact that $E(u(Y))=\int\limits_\mathbb Ru(y)f_Y(y)\mathrm dy$ for every function $u$.